# Android MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission request return -1. My app is system app

Tags: android, android-studio

So I've installed my application as system app thanks to [this](https://www.androidauthority.com/install-user-app-as-system-app-how-to-93522/). I've done from **adb** as it's described there. And my app is system app as I see in my rooted phone.

Now my problem is MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission still returns -1 even tho my app is system app. My system is Android 7.1.2.

here is a code:

```
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(grantResults.length == 0){
        System.out.println("This DENSE ain't answering");
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == MODIFY_PHONE_STATE && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            if(telephonyManager.hasCarrierPrivileges()) {
                System.out.println("TRUE hasCarrierPrivileges");
            }else{
                System.out.println(telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName());
                System.out.println("FALSE hasCarrierPrivileges");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("TRUE MODIFY_PHONE_STATE");

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("False MODIFY_PHONE_STATE " + grantResults[0]);
    }
}
```

Output is sadly: `False MODIFY_PHONE_STATE -1.` 
In Manifest I've got this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove tools:ignore from manifest and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks for response.  It gives same result.